# Get LDAP User information from HttpServerletRequest in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, ldap, weblogic

My team is migrating a java application from Weblogic to Jboss, when the user has consumed the app, this calls the method `getUserFromSession`.

The problem is when we get ldap information because this code does not work in Jboss the return error is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.getInternalAttribute(java.lang.String)

The code to change is as follows, can you help me with some option to get that information something similar to what is currently in place for weblogic

```
public static UserBean getUserFromSession(HttpServletRequest request) throws SessionExpiredException {
    try {
        Method methodSession = request.getSession().getClass().getMethod("getInternalAttribute", String.class);
        Object authUser = null;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (authUser == null && attempts < 30) {
            authUser = methodSession.invoke(request.getSession(), "weblogic.authuser");
            if (authUser == null) {
                attempts++;
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
        }
        if (authUser != null) {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String authUserString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authUser);
            Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", authUserString);
            if (!authUserString.contains("MAD_Extr_PrivateChannels_Aut")) {
                Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", "User does not have MAD_Extr_PrivateChannels_Aut role");
                throw new Exception("Your user does not have a role assigned for Private Channel");
            }
            if (!authUserString.contains("air")) {
                Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", "User does not have air cn");
                throw new Exception("Your user does not have an airline assigned");
            }

            TypeReference<HashMap> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap>() {
            };
            Map mapUser = objectMapper.readValue(authUserString, typeRef);
            List principals = (List) mapUser.get("principals");
            mapUser = (Map) principals.get(0);
            String[] dn = mapUser.get("dn").toString().split(",");
            Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", "User dn: " + mapUser.get("dn"));
            if (dn.length < 3) {
                Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", "User does not have 3 parts in dn");
                throw new Exception("Your user does not have an airline properly");
            }

            UserBean response = new UserBean();

            response.setAirlineCode(dn[2].replace("ou=", "").toUpperCase());
            response.setUserName(dn[0].replace("cn=", ""));
            Tools.addLogEntry("private_channel.log", "User name: " + mapUser.get("name"));
            response.setUserId(mapUser.get("name").toString());

            return response;
        } else {
            throw new SessionExpiredException();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new SessionExpiredException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. You can edit your question and add the text.

Comment: thanks @tgdavies i changed my question with your suggestion